# How to split a column when having multiple scenarios (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that has a combination of longitude and latitude. I'm trying to split them separately. But, I'm facing a problem. Here's what my data looks like:

```
print(df['location'])

                     location
0         -10.8544921875-49.8238090851324
1          2.021484375-59.478568831926
2          2.021484375 / 49.823809085
3          -10.8544921875/ 59.478568831926
4          9.61795 19.33163
```

As you can see some don't have any spacing but separated with a ' - '. Some have spacing a separated with ' / '. And other have spacing without any character between them.

I've tried to separate it one by one and firstly by doing:

```
 df[['Long','Lat']] = df['location'].str.split(" ",1, expand=True)
```

Obviously, it didn't separate everything.

My problem is, what do I do next or is there a better approach using Regular Expression? which I'm not familiar with at all

Desired Output:

```
               long              Lat
0        -10.8544921875     -49.8238090851324
1           2.021484375     -59.478568831926
2           2.021484375      49.823809085
3        -10.8544921875      59.478568831926 
4           9.61795          19.33163
```

Comment: Is the "-" definitely spacing?  It can be part of the latitude and longitude values

Comment: @Plato77 Yes it is. I've check the data and found it separates between latitude and longitude.

Comment: What I'm saying is that a negative value in latitude or longitude can be part of the value?  Therefore you shouldn't remove it as part of data cleaning

Comment: kindly post a visual of ur final output

Comment: @Plato77 Oh I get it. Thanks for the info, so as you said I need the negative sign

Comment: @sammywemmy Added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df[['Long','Lat']] = df['location'].str.extractall(r'([-]?\d+(\.\d+)?)')[0].unstack(level=1)
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> df[['Long','Lat']]

             Long                Lat
0  -10.8544921875  -49.8238090851324
1     2.021484375   -59.478568831926
2     2.021484375       49.823809085
3  -10.8544921875    59.478568831926
4         9.61795           19.33163
```